# Deleting weekend data in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database, datatables

I have some tables in MySQL db. My table has date as one of its columns and has data for last one year. I want to delete the data of weekends since that is of no use to me. Is it possible to delete the weekend data from these db tables with an SQL query ?

Comment: Are you want to delete records every weekend?

Comment: Never delete the data - this is an irreversible action. Move it into archive table.

Comment: yes @VinayKaklotar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`DAYOFWEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek):

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(date_col) IN (1, 7);
```

The above query would target for deletion any record happening to fall on a Saturday (7) or Sunday (1).

Comment: That's a really convenient query, right there. Haven't seen one like it before

Answer (score 1):

There is inbuild function in mysql to find days of week.

```
delete from table where DAYOFWEEK(date) in (1,7)
```

where 1 = Sunday, 7 = Saturday